# How to draw a diary in swt

Tags: java, swing, swt

I am searching for a good mode to develop a application which shows 7 days and 24 hours (weekly view), knows somebody if there is a good tutorial? Or which layout would you use to design this?

It should be possible to add events with a beginning and ending time...

Thanks in advance
Johannes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, we did it using Panels (one Panel for every Day) and gave them a hight of 24hours * 2px/minute. 
Than we created a JEventButton which is inhertied by JButton and placed the button on the Panel for example a Event beginning at 10am until 12am began at pixel (2 * 60 * 10) and had a hight of (2 * 60 * 2) pixels.

I hope this helps somebody else and would be thankful about other opinions.